# Cordova social sharing succes sharing

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I use this plugin for sharing: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

But Is it possible to understand the user did Sharing or not using it?
For in app points.
Thanks!

Comment: firebase analytic may help in this.

Comment: you can use callbacks as documented in plugin https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#using-the-share-sheet

Comment: callbacks call after share popup show..